# Flutter appbar whiteout with with WebViewWidget

Tags: ios, flutter, wkwebview

i have run the [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) example app, and on the iPhone simulator the appear gets white color immediately webpage is loaded.(iOS 14.5 iPhone 12, iOS 16.4 iPhone 14,14 pro)
Android is OK.

I'll attach a [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UYFismC3dsKAozpRoBg3171R7R8Hs223/view?usp=sharing) about it.

Can someone help me why?

thanks!

edit: only with material2 style!

edit2: [NEW VIDEO](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14y_OHI8oGGhn5OYQDU19nabwV07CXUXG/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Have you tried to erase all the content of your iPhone Simulator and start a new one formatted?

Comment: I created a new simulator and tried. The same. Monday i will try a phisical device

Comment: Which version of webview_flutter are you using?

Comment: Its the same error with 4.2.2 and 3.0.4. I updated the video